# Automatically copy content to range of cells in excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Below is my **initial** excel sheet

[image]

Below is what my **output** should be

[image]

My approach:

- Get the first value from column A

  Get the Offset(0,1) of column A (results in B1)

  Get the number of records from column B till the first empty cell (results in 3)
  Copy value of A1 to the cells (number of records - 1) below A1
- Loop for all the 3 values in column A

I have implemented till I get the addresses of the cells with values in column A. Below is my code.

```
  Dim currentRow As Integer
  Dim element As Variant
  Dim totalRows As String
  Dim offsetrow As String
  Dim offsetcell As Variant

  totalRows = Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
  MsgBox (totalRows)


  For currentRow = 1 To totalRows
    If (IsEmpty(Cells(currentRow, 1).Value)) Then

    Else
        Cells(currentRow, 1).Select
        offsetcell = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Address

        'Do the rest
    End If
  Next

End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You could optimize this by using arrays but this is the basic idea:

```
Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = "" And Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" And Cells(i + 1, 2).Value <> "" Then
        Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Hi Ripster, thanks for your help :)
the thing is the number of records vary each time. So can't use arrays. Anyways I came up with a work around. I posted it below.

Comment: When you declare the array you don't have to specify its size. This allows you to use ReDim to declare the size of the array later on after you know how large it needs to be. Using this method you can create an array that has the correct size each time your code runs.

Answer (score 0):

This is my work around to achieve the desired output. This might not be the most efficient way of doing this. Anyways it works :).

```
Sub Button1_Click()

  Dim currentRow As Integer
  Dim totalrows As String
  Dim offsetrow As Integer
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim row As Integer


  totalrows = Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row


  For currentRow = 1 To totalrows
    If (IsEmpty(Cells(currentRow, 1).Value)) Then

    Else
        Cells(currentRow, 1).Select
        offsetrow = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).row

        row = offsetrow

        i = 1
        Do While (Cells(row, 2).Value <> "")
            i = i + 1
            row = row + 1
            Cells((row - 1), 1).Value = Cells(currentRow, 1).Value

        Loop

    End If
  Next

End Sub
```

Hope this helps to anyone come across the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternate solution:

To accurately determine the number of rows for your range:

```
Lastrow = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
```

An alternate method for your problem:

Manual

1. select range in column a,
2. go to blanks (ctrl+g),
3. press =, up arrow. Now hold ctrl+Enter
4. Copy/paste as values...

Here's a code snippet to do this:

```
Lastrow = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
Range("A1:A" & Lastrow).Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
Range("A1:A" & Lastrow).Value = Range("A1:A" & Lastrow).Value
```

Finish off by looping through column B and deleting A values where B is blank.

Hope this helps.